# Getting vim shebang plugin working

Tags: vim, shebang

Sorry if this is a silly question, I'm brand new to Vim.

I've downloaded the following shebang plug-in (http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3366 version 1.1) to the directory .vim/plugin

When I open a file (e.g. "vim pypr.py") and in type in ":\X [enter]" (in normal mode) I encounter the following error:

"E10: \ should be follow by /, ? or &"

My .vimrc file in its entirety is as follows:

```
execute pathogen#infect() 
syntax on 
filetype plugin indent on

syntax enable 
set background=dark 
colorscheme solarized

map <leader>X :w<CR>:call SetExecutable()<CR>
```

I googled the error, and the results were not helpful in resolving the problem.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I suspect I just don't know how to use the leader command.

Comment: Edit: I should not have been entering command mode with ":" before typing the backslash. I had a LaTeX plugin that was not loading properly which was causing an error beep when I tried pressing backslash.

This was helpful: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6649/error-beep-from-backslash-key-unable-to-use-as-localleader-gvim-windows-8

Answer (score 1):

The mapping

```
map <leader>X :w<CR>:call SetExecutable()<CR>
```

says to enter `\X` where `\` is leader's default value. You can find the current leader value by

```
:let mapleader
```

It is `\` if it says `Undefined variable` or it will show the current leader value.

---

Or you can map to another key like <kbd>F6</kbd> so that pressing <kbd>F6</kbd> will achieve what you are looking

```
nnoremap <F6> :w<CR>:call SetExecutable()<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

With mapping you don't need `:` and `[Enter]` — just type `\X`.

Comment: Yep, see above. I had another error that was preventing "\" from working.